# Java IPC with Mappedbus - reset file on EOF

Tags: java, ipc

I am using Mappedbus for IPC between two JVMs (oracle jdk 1.8, linux arm);
I would like to see the IPC work "forever", but as the memory mapped (or shared memory) file is finite, before or later the writer gets an EOFException.

So I try to reset the writer (and the reader), but after closing and reopening the writer, the reader is not able to read the new records.

So, the question is, **how to make the following test case work i.e. go on forever with both writer and reader working?**

```
 // intentionally low, for this test case
 final long FILE_SIZE = 2000L;

 private final String fileName = "/dev/shm/ipc-message";

 @Test
 public void hello() throws IOException {

    MappedBusReader reader;

    MappedBusWriter writer;
    writer = new MappedBusWriter(fileName, FILE_SIZE, 128, false);

    writer.open();  

    reader = new MappedBusReader(fileName, FILE_SIZE, 128);

    reader.open();        

    int writeCounter = 0;
    int readCounter = 0;

    while (true) {

        IpcMessage message = new IpcMessage();

        message.source = 1; 

        message.value = 1;
        message.destination = 2;

        message.body = new byte [32];

        try {

            writer.write(message);       

        } catch (EOFException ex) {
            System.out.println("write EXCEPTION");

            writer.close();

            writer = new MappedBusWriter(fileName, FILE_SIZE, 128, false);

            writer.open();  
        }

        System.out.println("write: " + writeCounter++);

        try {
            if (reader.next()) {

                    boolean recovered = reader.hasRecovered();
                    int type = reader.readType();

                    System.out.println("read: " + readCounter++);

                    reader.readMessage(message);   

            }
        }  catch (EOFException ex) {

            System.out.println("read EXCEPTION");

            reader.close();

            reader = new MappedBusReader(fileName, FILE_SIZE, 128);

            reader.open(); 

        }

    }



 }
```

where IpcMessage is:

```
public class IpcMessage implements MappedBusMessage, Serializable {

    public static final int TYPE = 0;

    public int messageType;
    public int value;

    public int source;
    public int destination;


    @Override
    public void write(MemoryMappedFile mem, long pos) {

        mem.putInt(pos, messageType); 
        mem.putInt(pos + 4, value); 

        mem.putInt(pos + 8, source);
        mem.putInt(pos + 12, destination);
    }

    @Override
    public void read(MemoryMappedFile mem, long pos) {

        messageType = mem.getInt(pos);
        value = mem.getInt(pos + 4);

        source = mem.getInt(pos + 8);
        destination = mem.getInt(pos + 12); 

    }

    @Override
    public int type() {
        return TYPE;
    }



}
```

The output I get from this test case is:

```
write: 0
read: 0
write: 1
read: 1
write: 2
read: 2
...
write: 8
read: 8
write: 9
read: 9
write: 10
read: 10
write: 11
read: 11
write: 12
read: 12
write: 13
read: 13
write EXCEPTION
write: 14
write: 15
write: 16
write: 17
write: 18
write: 19
write: 20
write: 21
write: 22
write: 23
```

Comment: I would hazard a guess that you'll get much better performance from sockets as it seems like you're doing linear IO anyway, although it depends on the use case of course.

Comment: See e.g. [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9251718/2873896) to a similar question. FWIW, a SHM is *not* a memory mapped *file*, where disk IO will cost you a lot of performance and add complexity like managing the EOF.

Comment: @LukeBriggs: actually I have three processes in distinct JVMs which communicate among them, so maybe a multicast socket solution like Jgroups could be the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received an answer to my question via email from the developer of Mappedbus, I think it is interesting so I copy it here:

> This question was briefly answered here:
>   https://github.com/caplogic/Mappedbus/issues/1
>
> In short, mappedbus is meant for scenarios where you need to store all
>   messages.  If you don't need to do this, it might not be the right
>   solution.
>
> If you do need to store them, just make the file large enough to be
>   able to contain all messages during in the life cycle of the system
>   (for example for one day). And then have a time where you stop all
>   components, rename the file and start them again.